# Null output for derived class attributes

Tags: java, orm, polymorphism, eclipselink

I was able to map my models with entities using SINGLE_TABLE Inheritance strategy like in this tutorial
https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Entities/Inheritance#Avoiding_Inheritance

The Base class is initialized fine but when I'm trying to access the most derived part attributes, I get null values.

Since I'm a beginner in EcpliseLink / Hibernate I assume the problem is in mapping...

**Base Class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="event")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "EVENT_TYPE")
public abstract class Events implements Serializable {

    public Events(){

    }

     public Events(java.sql.Date date, int totalPlaces, int availablePlaces, String shortDescription,
                  String longDescription) {
        Date = date;
        TotalPlaces = totalPlaces;
        AvailablePlaces = availablePlaces;
        ShortDescription = shortDescription;
        LongDescription = longDescription;
        this.location = location;
        this.picture = picture;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected int Id;

    @Basic(optional=false)
    protected Date Date;

    @Basic(optional=false)
    protected String Company;

    @Basic(optional=false)
    protected int TotalPlaces;

    @Basic(optional=false)
    protected int AvailablePlaces;

    @Column(nullable = true, name="ShortDescription")
    protected String ShortDescription;

    @Column(nullable = true, name="LongDescription")
    protected String LongDescription;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="Id")
    protected Location location;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="Id")
    protected Pictures picture;

    abstract public String getCompany() {
        return "Hochschule";
    }

    public void setCompany(String company) {
        //
    }

    abstract public Double getPrice();

    public void setPrice(Double price) {
        //
    }

    abstract public void identify();

    //gtrs strs
```

**Derived Part**

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value="EXCURSION")
public class Excursion extends Events {

    public Excursion(){

    }

    public Excursion(java.sql.Date date, Double price, int totalPlaces, int availablePlaces, String shortDescription, String longDescription) {
        super(date, totalPlaces, availablePlaces, shortDescription, longDescription);
        this.Price = price;
    }

    @Basic(optional=false)
    private Double Price;

    @Override
    public Double getPrice() {
        System.out.println("Derived Part getPrice called ");
        return Price;
    }

    @Override
    public String getCompany(){
        return "Hochschule Ulm";
    }

    @Override
    public void setPrice(Double price) {
        Price = price;
    }

    @Override
    public void identify(){
        System.out.println("This is Excursion");
    }
}
```

**Main**

```
        List<Events> ls = em.createNamedQuery("Events.findAllEvents").getResultList();

        for(Events e : ls){
            e.identify();
            System.out.println(e.getId()+" "+e.getPrice());
            // getPrice() returns null for every record
        }

    }
```

Comment: How are you creating and persisting Excursions? What does the row in the DB look like for one that has a price? Is the query returning an instance of Excursion with a null price or is they some other Event subclass instance?

Comment: @Chris The query returns instances of subclasses actually, I used e.indentify() to verify. The Db row is the same for the subclasses. price, company are nullable and they have default values in DB. Example of how Excursion is created:

`Excursion e1 = new Excursion(date, price, totalPlaces, availablePlaces, shortDescription, longDescription)`

Then I use entityManager to persist it.

Comment: What SQL statements that were issued?  Both for the query and for the insert? Using default values can have strange behaviour with caching. If your instance's value is null when you call persist, that is the value you will get back until you refresh it from the database using em.refresh or restart your application.

Comment: @Chris I didn't use SQL statements for insertion at all. I used MySQL workbench to test, entities are persisted correctly, default values are assigned by DB.
Btw I already solved the problem, thanks for hint anyways.

Comment: The JPA spec, and all EclipseLink unit tests as well as my own show that if you query for a root class, it builds and returns the subclass instances fine. If you are ok with issuing multiple queries instead of being able to query the parent in an inheritance hierarchy, so be it, but your answer doesn't seem like a long term solution to me, and seems like you are using a model that doesn't have the inheritance set correctly.  For the SQL being issued, you need to set the EclipseLink log level appropriately to log what it is using: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I fixed myself this issue. The derived part was simply not getting initialized. When I fetch all Events from DB, only the base part of the events were initialized. The way I found to do it is, to fetch all subclasses separately then store them in a List

```
List<Excursion> le = em.createNamedQuery("Excursion.findAllExcursions").getResultList();
List<CompanyExcursion> lc = em.createNamedQuery("CompanyExcursion.findAllExcursions").getResultList();

List<Events> ls = new ArrayList<>();
ls.addAll(le);
ls.addAll(lc);
```